# React Native upgrade version to 0.63 from 0.61.5+ TypeError:

Tags: react-native, versionupgrade

ERROR    TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.TouchableOpacity.propTypes.style')

ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)

ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by replacing TouchableOpacity.propTypes.style with Text.propTypes.style